# Composite reliability for a simple parallel model

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, reliability

I want to calculate the composite reliability for a simple parallel model as follow.

[image]

And the below is what the textbook says (you can skip this part if you want)

When X is a composite score, using A and B

$X=A+B$

Then the $X$ can be expressed as what A and B have in common ($V$) and what is unique ($U$).

$X=aV+U_A+bV+U_B=(a+b)V+U_A+U_B$

and the variance of X is

$s_x^2=(a+b)^2s^2_V+c+d$

So, the composite reliability ($\omega$) is

$\omega=\frac{(a+b)^2s^2_V}{(a+b)^2s_V^2+c+d}$

And the textbook says for the model above, the $\omega$ is as follow.

$\omega=\frac{(0.818+0.818)^2}{(0.818+0.818)^2+0.331+0.331}=0.80$

But my question here is what happened to $s_v^2$?

It magically disappeared or is it simply considered to be 1?

If it is 1, I want to know why.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm guessing your textbook (like most articles on the subject) simply assume you fixed s^2_v = 1 for identification, thus allowing it to be omitted from the equation.